# Using recv with MSG_WAITALL and MSG_PEEK

Tags: windows, tcp, peek

I know that using MSG_PEEK is bad practice but in my current implementation of a tcp-client I must read just the first 4 bytes from the network buffer. I only have to check if those 4 bytes converted to an int have a value I am looking for. Can I use MSG_WAITALL with MSG_PEEK to get those 4 bytes or will this method crash everything?